# SQL Stored Procedure with one parameter and several variables that will change over time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am attempting to build a stored procedure with variables that will change over time. on SP execution (Right clicking SP in programmability under the database and execute) results in

Error output:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'file20160303FROMx:'.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

I am really open to any feedback, be it a complete re-design if need be. Still a junior in this field.

Script:

```
USE [dbname]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[procname]    Script Date: 2016-03-03 09:45:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


 --=============================================
 --Author:      <Author,,Name>
 --Create date: <Create Date,,>
 --Description: <Description,,>
 --=============================================
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[procname]
@p1 nvarchar(8)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @insertvariable NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @var1 NVARCHAR (32) = 'x:\xxxx\xxxx\file\err';
Declare @var2 NVARCHAR (15) = convert(varchar, getdate(),112) + '.' + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','')
Declare @var3 NVARCHAR (MAX) = @var1 + @var2 + '.log';
Declare @var4  NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'x:\xxxx\xxxx\file';
Declare @var5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = @var2 + @p1 + '.tab.txt';
Declare @formatFile NVARCHAR (MAX) = 'x:\xxxx\xxxx\formatFile';

set @insertvariable =  N'
BULK INSERT dbname.dbo.tablename' + @p1 + 'FROM' + @var5 + 'WITH 
    (
   FIRSTROW = 1,
   ORDER (Id),
   CODEPAGE = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = \t,
   ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a,
   TABLOCK,
   ERRORFILE = @var3,
   FORMATFILE = @formatFile, 
   KEEPNULLS
   );'
   exec sp_executesql @insertvariable, N'@p1 nvarchar, @var5 nvarchar, @var3 nvarchar, @formatFile nvarchar', @p1, @var5, @var3, @formatFile 
   end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing spaces in your concatenated string and you also need to quote your filename.
I also don't see the point of mixing concatenation and calling sp_executesql with parameters.

Try changing this part:

```
set @insertvariable =  N'
BULK INSERT dbname.dbo.tablename' + @p1 + 'FROM' + @var5 + 'WITH 
    (
   FIRSTROW = 1,
   ORDER (Id),
   CODEPAGE = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = \t,
   ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a,
   TABLOCK,
   ERRORFILE = @var3,
   FORMATFILE = @formatFile, 
   KEEPNULLS
   );'
   exec sp_executesql @insertvariable, N'@p1 nvarchar, @var5 nvarchar, @var3 nvarchar, @formatFile nvarchar', @p1, @var5, @var3, @formatFile 
   end
```

Into this, mind the spaces where you concatenate @p1 and @var5 and single quotes:

```
set @insertvariable =  N'
BULK INSERT dbname.dbo.tablename ' + @p1 + ' FROM ''' + @var5 + ''' WITH 
    (
   FIRSTROW = 1,
   ORDER (Id),
   CODEPAGE = ''Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS'',
   FIELDTERMINATOR = \t,
   ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a,
   TABLOCK,
   ERRORFILE = ''' + @var3 + ''',
   FORMATFILE = ''' + @formatFile + ''', 
   KEEPNULLS
   );'
   exec sp_executesql @insertvariable
   end
```